# Taking input from stdin after freopen()

Tags: c++, c

Hi I want to how can we take input from `stdin` again after I invoke:

```
freopen("Smefile.txt","r",stdin);
```

Precisely I want my first in first of my program should take input from a designated file the next part would take from the stdin.

Like:

```
 int a,b;
 freopen("Smefile.txt","r",stdin);
 scanf("%d",&a);

 {
   //some block here such that the next cin/scanf takes b from standard input
 }
 cin>> b;
 cout <<a<<" "<<b;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use a second file handle for your file, rather than re-using `stdin`?

Comment: There maybe workarounds to what PO wans to achieve, but the question itself is of value in it's own accord. Is it possible to take input from stdin after using freopen() for a file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. Use

```
FILE *input = fopen("Smefile.txt","r");

// read stuff from file

fclose(input);
input = stdin;
```

instead.

This won't help when you're mixing C++ and C-style I/O on the same stream, which I wouldn't recommend anyway.

(If you happen to be on Linux, you can reopen `/dev/stdin` instead. On Linux/Unix, you can also use Jerry Coffin's `dup2` trick, but that's even hairier.)

Comment: I don't understand how does this helps my purpose? My application need to read the whole file first and then from the standard input.

Comment: If on Windows, the `con` device name would work too (for both stdin and stdout).  Howver, I don't know how stderr could be reopened.

Comment: @Jeff M: which is also non-portable and the solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: Of course, but if you're going to mention the Unix variant, might as well include the Windows one as well.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly and (sort of) non-portable. You use `fileno` to retrieve the file descriptor associated with `stdin` and use `dup` to keep a copy of it. Then you do your `freopen`. When you're done, you use `dup2` to associate `stdin`'s file descriptor with the one you previously saved, so the standard stream points back where it started. See [redirect.c](https://github.com/LogicalKnight/snippets/blob/master/redirect.c) from the C snippets collection for demo code.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing C stdio and C++ IO streams this way is not valid. The results are undefined.