# What's the opposite of close(fd) in C?

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor

I am trying to make a mini shell where commands are piped to each other. At some points in the code I do:

```
close(1) //closing stdout
```

and

```
close(0) //closing stdin
```

However later on I am forking so I want my new subprocess to reset everything. So how would I:

```
*function_name_here*(1) //reopening stdout
```

and

```
*function_name_here*(0) //reopening stdin
```

Comment: You can't do that. Once the streams are closed, the "cease to exist".

Comment: See this question for examples of other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973905/taking-input-from-stdin-after-freopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a UNIX-type system (and you most likely *are* if you're calling `fork`), you can generally do one of two things.

The first is to open `/dev/tty` which will give you access to your terminal device (assuming the terminal device is what you want rather than the original file handle).

The second is to `dup` that file handle before you close it so you have a usable copy. Then, you can use `dup2` to get it back. Details for Linux [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2), or you could also execute `man dup` or `man dup2`.