# How to feed file input into C program in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a program that I built in Xcode however I need to supply input to the program in the following way as would be done from the Terminal:

```
./program < fileInput
```

I followed the steps suggested here [Running C scripts with terminal instead of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815061/running-c-scripts-with-terminal-instead-of-xcode) but no luck.

Below is the screenshot of my attempt. The file I'm providing exists in the Build directory. I also tried supplying the input file as absolute path without any luck either. My xcode version is 8.1.

The screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You can't do this with the `<` sign, this is processed by the shell. Maybe there is another way with XCode, but I don't know it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that kind of explains it. I guess I could use `argv[]` but I was really hoping `<` would work.

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973905/taking-input-from-stdin-after-freopen) will help you somewhat.